# IGBT Modules current ratings - do they refer to the sum of 3 paralleled IGBTs or to each one of them?

Tags: datasheet, parallel, igbt, module, current-rating

soon I'm gonna build a motor controller and that's why I've started searching some IGBT Modules .

The thing is - when I read some datasheets I see the current ratings but I don't understand what those ratings refer to because there are 3 parallel IGBTs in each module , so I wonder whether those ratings refer to each one of the IGBTs or to the total sum of current used by those 3 IGBTs at once...

here is one datasheet I came across : https://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/powermodule/hvigbt_ipm/h_series/cm900hb-90h_e.pdf

Comment: provide a datasheet and refer to the specification that is causing you the problem. The IGBT modules I've come across have three separate IGBT channels for three phases. These are not in parallel.

Comment: Oh I see , my bad , so - those three separate IGBTs are rated in reference to each single one of them ?

here is one datasheet I came across : https://www.mitsubishielectric.com/semiconductors/content/product/powermodule/hvigbt_ipm/h_series/cm900hb-90h_e.pdf

Comment: Please add the datasheet to the post, so readers don't have to sort through the comments to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IGBTs in your module are indeed parallel except the collectors. My understanding of this datasheet is, that the 900 A current rating is for all 3 IGBTs parallel, however, I could not find a note mentioning this. The top feature list says "1-element in a pack" and since the gates and emitters are internally connected parallel, the datasheet describes one big IGBT.